# How to extract youtube id from HTML?

Tags: regex, xpath

How to extract "data-id" from this html in format `youtube.com/data-id` (youtube.com/wXlBep9uFjI)?

```
<div class="video card no_border">
    <div class="wrapper" style="background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wXlBep9uFjI/hqdefault.jpg');">
        <a class="no_click play_trailer" href="/video/play?key=wXlBep9uFjI" data-site="YouTube" data-id="wXlBep9uFjI" data-title="Disney's Artemis Fowl - Teaser Trailer">
            <div class="play_background">
                <span class="glyphicons_v2 play invert svg"></span> 
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which language you need to do it in ?

Comment: Are you sure that regex is the right way? maybe you should give a try to an xPath query.

Comment: What xPath query please?

Answer (score 0):

Using a [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) query:

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//a[@data-site="YouTube"]/@data-id)' file.html
```

You can use [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) too :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v 'string(//a[@data-site="YouTube"]/@data-id)' file.html
```

Or [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -se 'string(//a[@data-site="YouTube"]/@data-id)' file.html
```

## Output:

```
wXlBep9uFjI
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to do it from a Linux terminal commandline - suppose the HTML is in a file called page.html

```sh
$ sed -rn 's/^.* data-id="([^"]+)".*/youtube.com\/\1/p' page.html
youtube.com/wXlBep9uFjI
```

The sed command matches the data-id value with a pattern in parentheses - if there's a match, the parentheses create a backreference that can be used as `\1` in a replacement string